# Continuously shift "selected" vertices in a graph so that none get squished.

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, fluid-dynamics

[Suppose that we are doing a computer simulation of a dwarf kingdom.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711476/random-walk-on-a-pointed-container) There is an underground
labyrinth of some shape and size, inhabited by some number of dwarves. Every dwarf is arbitrarily
moving around, but at all times obeying two laws of dwarf physics:

- The movement of dwarves must be continuous.
- The amount of dwarves must remain constant.

Given a specific setting of dwarves in a labyrinth, what can I know of their locations at some
point in the future?

---

One formalization I can invent — follows:

$\textbf{definition}\quad$ Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ with some *"selection"* of vertices $S
\subset V$, $S' \subset V$ is a *"shift"* of $S$ if they can be put into 1:1 correspondence so
that the corresponding vertices are no more than 1 edge apart. $\square$

Then I ask whether we can **enumerate all possible shifts of a given selection**, and the number of
ways each shift may be attained. This would allow us to probabilistically precompute the outcome
of any number of shifts.

But I also see some analogy with, should I say, fluid dynamics: there are tangible, distinctly
painted particles floating around in a continuum, obeying the same laws of continuity and
preservation stated above — like some droplets of oil in a bowl of soup. Could this line of
reasoning lead a more educated person than myself to some interesting quantitative results?

Is there some deep generalization here waiting to be discovered?

---

**P.S.**   I have accepted an answer because it is actually an awesome solution to the problem in the formulation I had put forward. But I am still looking for some kind of unification with the continuous.

Comment: I don't see what your graph definition has to do with the dwarf movement. Presumably you want to have the dwarf at vertex $v$ travel continuously along edge $e$ to vertex $v'$ if $v'$ is the "shift" of $v$ and they are separated by edge $e$. But this is a much stricter kind of movement than you initially described.

Comment: @kccu I am not sure I see what kinds of movement you have in mind that are completely at odds with some plausible extension of the graph definition I offer.

Comment: Anything that's not a union of straight lines?

Comment: @kccu Edges may represent arbitrarily short segments of the ways in the labyrinth, thus giving us arbitrary approximation to the real situation. We can always cut an edge into smaller edges and simulate more precisely; we can have multiple parallel edges or weighted edges to represent the width of the hallways, and weighted vertices to represent the expanse of the halls. I do not argue that this is the best and only representation of a dwarf kingdom possible, it is just that I can see how to make it work. I welcome any other way to put this situation in computable terms.

Comment: Then you're talking about a huge graph, which is going to make computation and enumeration very difficult. Honestly this question is too broad for MSE. Without more assumptions, you can't say anything about the dwarves' future positions - anything is possible, and there is no way to say what is more or less likely since you have not made any assumptions about what is probable/improbable.

Comment: @kccu? Too broad? The question is a very concrete question about specific computation in graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boils down to enumerating perfect matchings in a bipartite graph.

For a set $S \subseteq V(G)$, construct an auxiliary bipartite graph - not quite a subgraph - as follows:

- On one side ($A$), you have all the vertices in $S$.
- On the other side ($B$), you have all the vertices of $G$ adjacent to $S$. If there are vertices of $S$ adjacent to $S$, they appear on this side, again.
- Put an edge between the two sides whenever that edge appears in $G$.

We should have $|A| \le |B|$ if there is any way for the dwarves to successfully move. Of course, you may allow the dwarves to sit still (approximating continuous motion along a path that goes nowhere), in which case all of $S$ is contained in $B$ as well, and this is guaranteed to hold.

A possible transition of the dwarves is a matching in this bipartite graph that saturates the vertices in $A$. Many people thinking about these problems like perfect matchings, which saturate both sides; we can obtain this by adding $|B|-|A|$ artificial vertices to $A$, which are adjacent to all of $B$. The artificial vertices will get matched to vertices of $B$ that are not the destination of any dwarf.

Unfortunately, counting perfect matchings in a graph is hard in general. This is one of the [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete) problems: the equivalent of NP-complete, for counting problems rather than for decision problems.

Fortunately, we can go through all the perfect matchings in a way that takes $O(|S|)$ time per matching. [This paper](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac97web.pdf) suggests several ways to do it. The problem is difficult mainly because there could be exponentially many perfect matchings. If you happen to have a dwarven network where the number of shifts is small for each $S$, then enumerating the shifts will not take long.

Finally, if you want to predict the dwarves' short-term state, this is going to be very hard with this approach, because the number of possible $S$ grows very quickly. However, long-term, the stationary distribution is relatively easy to describe: the probability of the dwarves occupying a set $S$ will be proportional to the number of shifts out of $S$.

Comment: This is awesome. How did you arrive to the last point, about the long-term state?

Comment: This is true of any symmetric random walk, where all transitions from a state are equally likely and where if you can go from $S$ to $S'$ then you can go from $S'$ back to $S$.

Comment: Can you advise me some literature where this is covered?

Comment: See for instance [these lecture notes](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~pavan/633/lec7.pdf). Equation (1.11) is the claim I'm referring to.

Comment: N.B. The stationary distribution may never actually be reached. For example, consider the complete graph on two nodes; the stationary distribution has half a dwarf on each node, which obviously isn't actually achievable except by averaging over multiple time steps.

Comment: @DanielWagner The stationary distribution is a distribution over *states*, not over dwarves. It assigns to each state (a subset $S \subseteq V$) a probability.

Comment: (We still should worry about periodicity. But if we take my suggestion and allow a dwarf to stay put from one time step to another, then we are aperiodic.)

Comment: Sure, stated more precisely, the stationary distribution is a 50-50 split between the states "the dwarf is on A" and "the dwarf is on B". But starting from any concrete (non-probabilistic) initial setup and taking random steps, the only two distributions we ever reach are "100% probability of the dwarf being on A" and "100% probability the dwarf being on node B"; we never reach the stationary distribution, nor even converge towards it.

Comment: @DanielWagner Right; I'm saying that if we allow dwarves to stay put as one possible transition, we do reach the stationary distribution. (And if we don't allow dwarves to stay put, then there are other cases which are more problematic: cases where the dwarves are getting squeezed into a small set and have nowhere to go.)